# NodeJs promise in loop is not get all of data result

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, sql-server, promise

I'm using `promise`.

Now I try to put the promise inside loop query, assume `result2['recordset']` have 2 data.

```
result2['recordset'].forEach(function(element, index){
    var query = new Promise((success, failure) => {
        request.query("SELECT M.id, M.name, M.link, M.project_idfk, M.icon FROM tbl_module M WHERE M.project_idfk = '" + element.project_idfk + "' AND M.id IN(SELECT module_idfk FROM tbl_access_module WHERE group_idfk = '" + element.group_idfk + "' AND role IS NOT NULL AND(role = 'CREATE' OR role = 'VIEW'))", function (err, result3){
            success(result3['recordset']);
            console.log(result3['recordset']);
        });
    });
});

query.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.json({ module: result });
})
```

When I tried to `console.log(result3['recordset']);` it can show me the all of both data.

```
[
{
    id: 6,
    name: 'Department',
    link: 'department',
    project_idfk: 2,
    icon: 'glyphicon-tasks'
  }
]
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Location',
    link: 'location',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-screenshot'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Device',
    link: 'device',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-hdd'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Floor Map',
    link: 'map',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-map-marker'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Notification',
    link: 'notificaction',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-globe'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Report',
    link: 'report',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-tasks'
  }
]
```

But why when I tried to `console.log(result);` it only show me the first data (no ID number 6)

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Location',
    link: 'location',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-screenshot'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Device',
    link: 'device',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-hdd'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Floor Map',
    link: 'map',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-map-marker'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Notification',
    link: 'notificaction',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-globe'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Report',
    link: 'report',
    project_idfk: 1,
    icon: 'glyphicon-tasks'
  }
]
```

Comment: `.forEach()` is not promise-aware so it does you absolutely no good at all to wrap your query inside a promise inside the `.forEach()` loop.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 is there any way how to handle this?

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with  the query results so in order to know what to recommend, we need to see what you're trying to do with them and see that code.  Also, we need to know whether the loop needs to be sequenced or each iteration can run in parallel.

Comment: And, it would help to know which database module from NPM you're using because most have an option for built-in promise support these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forEach on won't handle promises, Change that to map and use Promise.all to get results.

```
const promises = result2["recordset"].map(function (element, index) {
  return new Promise((success, failure) => {
    request.query(
      "SELECT M.id, M.name, M.link, M.project_idfk, M.icon FROM tbl_module M WHERE M.project_idfk = '" +
        element.project_idfk +
        "' AND M.id IN(SELECT module_idfk FROM tbl_access_module WHERE group_idfk = '" +
        element.group_idfk +
        "' AND role IS NOT NULL AND(role = 'CREATE' OR role = 'VIEW'))",
      (err, result) => {
        success(result["recordset"]);
        console.log(result["recordset"]);
      }
    );
  });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result); // list or all result
  // Do something and send response
  res.json({ module: result });
});
```